# Creating Content List

Tags: 7, nodes

I have an custom content type movie.By which users can create "movie" content.
The movie content type is simple containing a title, director's name and a poster.

Now,what i need is,  Each user should be able to create lists of movies.As example , one may create "10 most scariest movies" , "10 most comedy movies" etc.

I want the creation of list in the following way ,

1) User will give it a title to his list.

2) Then he will add movies to his list , which are already crated .(like the way one user can tag other user in facebook - user should be able to tag movies.)

3) After the list is created when a movie on a list is clicked, it should lead to the page of the corresponding movie.

How should i solve this problem??

I am using Drupal 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question should be expanded.  As it stands it incredibly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using Entity Reference  Module.

I made a custom content type - "Movie List" , and add a field of "Entity Reference" type , then made a reference to "Movie" content.